# PYQT5: Retrieve information of a certain button that was made in a for loop

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

I'm making a movie theatre management system in PYQT5 and I have made a GUI of several buttons on the home screen using a for loop with the Icon of the button being the movie poster. Now, when I click the poster, I want to open the booking screen with the information of that movie, however because I am using a for loop for the buttons, the information of the last movie in the list is being displayed

```
        for i in range(len(res)):
            if i < 6:
                mov = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
                mov.setObjectName(f"mov_{i}")
                mov.setGeometry(QRect(70 + 307*i, 185, 230, 326))
                mov.setIcon(QIcon("{}".format(res[i][1])))
                mov.setIconSize(QSize(260,345))
                mov.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
                mov.raise_()
                mov.clicked.connect(self.openbookingscreen)
                

        for i in range(6, len(res)):
            mov2 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            mov2.setObjectName(f"mov_{i}")
            mov2.setGeometry(QRect(70 + 307*(i-6), 585, 230, 326))
            icon = QPixmap(f"{res[i][1]}")
            scaled = icon.scaled(QSize(230, 326))
            mov2.setIcon(QIcon("{}".format(res[i][1])))
            mov2.setIconSize(QSize(260, 345))
            mov2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
            mov2.raise_()
            mov2.clicked.connect(self.openbookingscreen)
```

[This is the main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDdyc.jpg)

Now when I click on any of the movies, the Information that shows up is always of the movie "The Invitation" as it is the final item in the list. Is there a way to identify which button was clicked and have that movies name show up in the next window.

Comment: [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html).

Comment: There are around 50 buttons I need to make, and all of them should be evenly spaced. Can I add all the buttons to QButtonGroup using a for loop or do I have to do it individually?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? The documentation seems clear enough (which I assume you didn't attempt to read, or only skimmed).

Comment: I did read it, and I did add the buttons to QButtonGroup. I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the name of the button when it is clicked.

Comment: Why not just use `name = button.objectName()`? Or [set the id](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#addButton) to a unique value when adding the buttons to the group. This is all explained very simply and clearly in the documentation, if you take the time to read it properly.